Why do the forces on a Feynman Sprinkler balance out?
Apparently, in a Feynman sprinkler, the momentum imparted to the tube from sucking the fluid in is exactly balanced by the momentum imparted in the other direction when the fluid turns the bend. I get that from a conservation of momentum perspective, this has to be true, but while I understand how the latter force is imparted, I don't understand the former.
In the latter case, it's clear that the TUBE is imparting momentum onto the fluid as it turns the bend (I can imagine a particle hitting the tube as it goes round the corner and transferring its momentum in its original direction to the tube).
In the former case, I don't get how the TUBE is sucking the fluid in. At what point does the tube impart tangential momentum to the fluid (and vice versa)? My understanding would be that the reaction force would be at the pump.
I can use my misunderstanding to create a situation where conservation of momentum is not satisfied; maybe this will make it easier for you to see where I'm wrong:
Imagine a pump that sucks air downwards through a vertical tube. In this case the downward momentum given to the air is balanced by the upwards momentum given to the pump (which is transferred to the Earth if the pump is attached to the Earth).
Now bend the tube at a right angle. When the pump is run, sideways momentum is given to the air (and then the tube as the air turns the corner), but the "equal and opposite" force is still at the pump, and it's still upwards. So now we've created unbalanced upwards and sideways momentum.
What's gone wrong?

Can you provide your reference for the Feynman sprinkler problem?

@eshaya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler (main post now edited)

Feynman sprinkler's rotation principle

If we put an empty bottle (with air inside) into the deep sea, the axis of the bottle is horizontal and the mouth of the bottle is facing left. Then, let the bottle cap suddenly disappear (imagine the bottle cap suddenly disappearing), then the seawater will flow into the bottle, which is the movement of the seawater into the bottle. At the same time, the bottle also moves to the left. This is the result of the seawater behind the bottle pushing the bottle.
For Feynman sprinkler, water flows into the tube because the pressure in the tube is low. Water is pressed into the tube. The pressure of the water outside the tube is higher than the pressure inside the tube.
As shown in the figure, this is a top view of Feynman sprinkler. The red arrow represents the direction of water flow. The pressure at point C is greater than the pressure at point B, the pressure at point B is greater than the pressure at point A, and the pressure at point A is greater than the pressure at point D. So, theoretically, Feynman sprinkler will rotate in the direction of F1.
Welcome to discuss more details.

Thank you!!
I was a little confused at first so I'd like to clarify for anyone else reading:
For simplicity, let the bottle have a vacuum, not air. The bottle moves left because where there used to be water pressure on the cap (pushing to the right), there no longer is, so the net force from the water is to the left. What @enbin doesn't say is that once the water hits the inside of the bottle, it will push back to the right, killing its momentum. So the bottle will lunge to the left. But this is a 1-time lunge so when the flow is continuous, there's no net movement, as per Wikipedia.

Clarification continued:
When we have suction, as opposed to a disappearing cap, the equivalent to the lost water-pressure on the cap is the reduced pressure on the right-hand side of the tube in the diagram (because of water being sucked out of the right-hand side).

@Monkle Because I provided a link at the beginning to answer your question, this website believed that I had violated the rules, so I was banned for a month. Today, I was finally unbanned.

@Monkle  Even in the case of continuous flow, it can also rotate. You can imagine an infinitely long but massless cup.
There is a new video in the host's video of the link I gave you, which is a brand new experiment discussing the situation of continuous flow. Now I dare not provide the link to this video anymore, I am worried about being banned. You can go take a look.

@Monkle As shown in my diagram, because there is velocity inside the pipe, the pressure loss is not balanced.
